# Кластеризация изображений

Tags: javascript

У меня в наличии более 10.000 скриншотов разных страниц нашего сайта. Мне необходимо рассортировать скриншоты по папкам. В каждой папке должны содержаться только скриншоты одной страницы. Руками делать я это не хочу поэтому вопрос: как можно автоматизировать этот процесс? Все что мне удалось нагуглить это MobileNet для Tenserflow.js, но эта модель обучена распознавать  образы предметов, а мне необходимо классифицировать не зная что за предмет на изображении поэтому этот подход мне не подходит.

Comment: Чуть больше гугления и оказалось что задача кластеризации а не классификации

Comment: А в чем именно проблема? Можно задать сортировку файлов по названию, задай каждой группе одно название

Comment: Название файла это просто guid

Comment: А что нельзя к автоматический созданному `guid-названию` задать что-нить еще?

Comment: У меня уже есть эти картинки их очень много, просматривать каждую и изменять название я не хочу

Comment: Тогда не подскажу.....